# convert month name in varchar to date so as to order by month

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

A table  exists which stores month name in the form of string.. 
I want to order by year and month so as to get proper result.

```
year(string)  Month(string)  data
------------  ------------   ----
2012           August        bigbox
2012           December      samllbox
2013           April         samll box
2012           September     larg
```

I want to order by year and month. as in 2012,2013... 
Jan,feb,march....

I am aware of the method of
case statement when
Month = 'january' THEN 1
Month - FEB THEN 2

But i do'nt want to use this as the procedure will be too big..

Comment: You should have thought on that before selecting `string` as your data  type. You can look for a function in your DBMS and see how that could be handled.

Comment: If you can change the layout of your table, you should really use a datetime column, it's so much easier to use (ORDER BY datetime DESC) is all you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE
ORDER BY [year] DESC,
         DATEPART(month,[Month] + ' 01 ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),[YEAR]))
```

The above code will give you what you want , but i would strongly suggest you reconsider your design.

Right now you are reserving a string type field which would be at least 15 characters long. This field does not have any value than for display reasons. You could have a `DATETIME` field that would be much easier to short by (not having to do calculations there) and if you would like to display the name of the month you could use:

```
DATENAME ( month, DateField )
```

Comment: Why are you assuming SQL Server?

Comment: I am working on sql server 2008. And calso can you explain me this.. Bcz i get the result sorted by month name properly but its like           {2013 January
2013 January
2012 January}

Comment: i want the answer like..2013 jan, 2013 april, 2013 august, 2012 jan , 2012 march....

Comment: @MostyMostacho You are right. I just guessed, though i should ask first.

Comment: @user2637506 My new edit will order by year desc, month asc.

Comment: @user2637506 That's not how databases work. You should fix the root problem.

Comment: Thanks this was perfect... i did guess this.. but i had stored year in string format so was wondering will this do the job.. Any ways thank you veyr much for the quick help.. :-)

Comment: We meet again. :-) Please don't use shorthand like `MM`. To understand why, try `SELECT DATEPART(W,GETDATE()), DATEPART(Y,GETDATE());`. If you mean `MONTH`, just type `MONTH`.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Hehe, i had read that article of yours, and that is why i used `month` in the second example. The first one just slipped.

Comment: But you're still using `VARCHAR` without a length. :-(

Comment: @AaronBertrand Darn.....:-)

Answer (score 3):

Your best option is to use the proper date type. Otherwise, create a table (inline or physical) to map your string months.

```
SELECT 1 AS month, 'January' AS strMonth
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'February'
UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'March'
...
SELECT 12, 'December'
```

Then map this your table. [See a demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cc593b/1)

Comment: thanks but my procedure will be full of logics.. i wanted some in built function...

Comment: A built in function is not the solution when there is poor design.